# Code Signing (Authenticode) then get "The system cannot execute the specified program."

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing, signtool, authenticode

I have problems executing my application after code signing it with Authenticode. This is what I do:

- build a C++ application
- sign the executable
- execute the executable
- and the system responds with "The system cannot execute the specified program."

Details:

```
C:\temp\signtest>more SimpleApp.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        cout << "Hello World from Simple App!" << endl;
        return 0;
}


C:\temp\signtest>cl SimpleApp.cpp /c /EHsc

Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 17.00.61030 für x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

SimpleApp.cpp

C:\temp\signtest>link /INTEGRITYCHECK /OUT:SignedApp.exe SimpleApp.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\temp\signtest>signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /f Code-Signing-Key.p12 /p mysecretpwd SignedApp.exe
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed and timestamped: SignedApp.exe

C:\temp\signtest>SignedApp
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

The system error code according to WinDbg is:

```
Error Code 577: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged [ERROR_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH (0x241)]
```

I have purchased a DigiCert Code Signing certificate. It's root CA is in the certificate store.

How comes that? Why isn't the EXE executable anymore?

Answer (score 1):

It really took me a while to find out how to code sign the PE image correctly, keeping it executable at the same time: The cross certificate must be integrated into the embedded digital signature, and it must be a cross certificate that Microsoft explicitly trusts (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn170454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Sample:

```
signtool sign /f <private_key_file> /p <private_key_password> /ac <cross_certificate_ca> /d "<description>" /du "<description_url>" /t "timestamp_server_url" /v /ph <pe_image>
```

In my case:

```
signtool sign /f Code-Signing-Key.p12 /p mysecretpwd /ac DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.crt /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /v /ph SignedApp.exe
```

Looks much better now:

```
C:\temp\signtest>SignedApp
Hello World from SimpleApp!
```